# Caracteres Especiales (Etiqueta) PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una página donde en un cuadro de texto el usuario puede cambiar el link de un visor de gráficas a través de un `<iframe>` pero cuando coloca la ruta completa php no muestra nada. Lo que se coloca en el cuadro de texto es lo siguiente:

```
<iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODUzNTBlGItMmNhZDRjMWJmZDIwIiwidCI6IjczZDMyNTRhLTdiOTQtNDI4OS1hODNhLTI2YTJjYjA2NDZlYyJ9&pageName=ReportSection177d0170d6cea606577c" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

El textarea lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="iFrameGenie" name="iFrame" required></textarea>
```

y la paso a través de POST de la siguiente manera:

```
$IFRAME = filter_var($_POST['iFrame'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //iFRAME
```

Y el resultado es '', es decir nada, como puedo pasar completamente  para poder enviarla a una base de datos.

Les muestro una imagen de lo que se tendría que cargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: El `textarea` que nos muestras está vacío y, la pregunta no se entiende. ¿El `iframe` está dentro del `textarea` es lo que nos quieres decir?

Comment: Estas aplicando un filtro que justamente lo que hace es cargarse todos los tags, [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_string.asp)... ponlo así a ver si te funciona:  `$IFRAME = $_POST['iFrame'];`

Comment: El iframe es lo que se tiene que capturar en el text area, probe simple colocando dentro del textarea <Hola> El mayor que y menor que abre y cierra es el que impide pasar a php! También intente retirar el FILTER SANITIZE STRING y contua sin pasar la etiqueta del <iframe>

Comment: deberías colocar un ejemplo funcional para poder verlo. puede que estes haciendo otra cosa con el form y no lo estamos viendo

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoAlcocerJuárez El ejemplo funcional debe incluir todo el `<form>` en HTML para ver como haces el submit (quizás haces una validación en el submit tambien que desconocemos en javascript que ya limpia ese campo antes de llegar al PHP... si es así pon tambien el javascript relacionado con eso).

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no guardas solamente esto en la base de datos: `https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiODUzNT...` y construyes el `iframe` de forma programática cuando obtengas los datos de la BD. Por otra parte, no tiene ningún sentido aplicar filtros aquí, no aporta nada a la seguridad, porque no mostrarás el `iframe` en pantalla en este momento, sino que quieres guardar esa cadena en la BD, por tanto, lo que debes aplicar en este contexto sería **consultas preparadas**. Es importante que para cada caso apliques el tipo de seguridad correcto, cosa que no haces aquí.

Answer (score 0):

Una disculpa, salí de viaje. Encontré la solución de la siguiente forma:

```
$IFRAME_1 = htmlspecialchars('<iframe class="responsive-iframe" src=');
$IFRAME_2 = htmlspecialchars(' frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>');
$SRC = htmlspecialchars($_POST['iFrame']); //iFRAME
```

Lo que hago del lado del submit es tener Iframe_1 y Iframe_2 que es el inicio y fin, la parte de en medio es el http donde el usuario lo coloca en el `<textarea>` y los concateno para subirlo a la base de datos.

Respondiendo a la pregunta inicial con **htmlspecialchar** me respeta los caracteres especiales con los que inicia el code iframe